# Images in my stylesheet

Tags: css, image, include, location

I am trying to include a background image in a css file located here:

public_html/css/folder/style.css

and the image is located in

public_html/img/image.png

I tried using

```
background: url("../img/image.png");
```

How can I get to that image?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go up 2 steps in the directory structure:

```
background: url("../../img/image.png");
```